# run portable php development server

Tags: php

I have a php project and for development I use the php built-in server. For production I have a proper nginx+php-fpm environment. But now I notice it's not fast enough since it's single-threaded.

The multi-thread option (PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS) does not work in windows, so I can't use it. I also tried the WSL version, but that also does not work for me, as I need to install and maintain the WLS distro to keep it updated (the solution must be portable)

Is there any option to do this? My needs are:

- Must run in windows
- Must serve a PHP site in multi-threaded mode
- Must be portable (just copy a folder to any computer, run an executable and be done)

Comment: A comment, as I don't know about the multi-threaded bit, but you might want to try the exceleltn - and portable - https://laragon.org/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [XAMPP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/)? It has a portable version and is one of the most used PHP environments. Assuming you don't mind the Apache <-> nginx difference as from what I remember that can have differences in the code itself for certain functionalities.

But the most "portable", modern and professional solution for local testing environments is simply using Docker. You have to install the program, whether GUI or CLI, but it's more "portable" in terms of simplicity of usage on different systems by different users if you configure your container(s) well.

Comment: Docker is all but portable, it requires admin privileges to install and even sometimes to run containers. The fact that it spins off a Linux virtual machine means that it cannot be a simple file copy to run from some other location, you must reinstall the whole thing.

Comment: Read my answer again please. There are quotes around the word "portable" because it doesn't refer to traditional software portability that the author asked for, it refers to code portability which is way more important IMO. But if the author really has a quite unusual use case of going around with a USB stick or sending files to data cloud and running the website from that, then the 1st part of the answer covers that.

Answer (score 1):

As in previous answer, I would have recommended XAMPP. But I came across this recently, and is worth looking at:

- [Laragon](https://github.com/leokhoa/laragon) - "a portable, isolated, fast & powerful universal development environment for PHP, Node.js, Python, Java, Go, Ruby. It is fast, lightweight, easy-to-use and easy-to-extend."

I have not tried it yet though.